# MongoDB: Not authorized on Admin

Tags: mongodb, admin, createuser

I'm beginning to use MongoDB and have spent several hours troubleshooting without resolve. From what I understand, there first needs to be a root user before there can be an authorized/admin user.

I installed in `C:\mongodb\`, then setup --dbpath in `C:\mongodb\data` and --logpath in `C:\mongodb\logs\log.txt`.

I installed then ran the MongoDB service, accessible in the `services.msc`

My recipe to disaster was:
1. `mongo localhost`,
2. `use admin`
3. `db.createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: '123456', roles:['root']})`

Then get "Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser ....."

I am running MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5 and greatly appreciate any help that leads to a solution.

Thank you,
Leo

Comment: Now, that is strange. Restart mongo with authentication disabled and retry, please. Then, restart it using auth enabled and login with `mongo admin -u root -p` and try to add other users. Btw, it makes sense to have a dedicated [user admin user](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#create-the-system-user-administrator).

Comment: I figured it out. I accidentally put the data and logs in same drive/folder, I guess it spat errors because of it.

I put the new data/logs in the D drive, and now it works. (9 hours of troubleshooting to come to this point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I accidentally put the data and logs in same directory as the `\mongodb\bin`. The solution is to put the `mongodb\data` and `mongodb\logs` in a separate folder or drive -- I differentiated using `C:\~` and `D:\~` drives.